# How to effectively Merge in sql

Tags: sql, merge, query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a source table.

```
id  description             test
12  this is the some value   0
10  this is the old value    5
```

And a temp table.(consists of latest changes which needed to be updated in source table)

```
id  description                 test
10  this is the new value        15
14  this is the some new value   5
```

Desired output is-> `select * from source_table;` should give me:

```
id  description                 test
10  this is the new value        15
14  this is the some new value   5
12  this is the some value       0
```

Trying to use something like this-

```
merge into source_table using temp_table 
    on source_table.id = temp_table.id
    when matched then 
        delete;
insert into source_table (select * from temp_table);
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this in 1 single query(I am trying to avoid update) ?

Comment: "I am trying to avoid update", why?

Comment: Trying to generalize this actually and this would be running for many tables without knowing the column names in the first place and also updates are slow in nature(observed).

Comment: `insert into source_table (select * from temp_table)` is  a rather dangerous generalization  without table definitons.

Comment: Yes but i am using something like this when creating both these tables
`create table temp_table like source_table; `

-> And all the new changes are coming to temp table, in the end i just have to club all the data in source_table

Comment: Actual problem i am trying to solve is: 
`"delete from $tableName where $dpPrimaryKey in " (select $PrimaryKey from $tempTableName);  `
`insert into $tableName (select * from $tempTableName);"`

I have these 2 individual statements i want to get the desired result in 1 query.
So i am exploring Merge / https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html

Comment: Merge generaly doesn't support  delete + insert when matched.

Comment: Yes thats the challenge what should be the ideal way to handle this case.

Comment: To give you more context why i am doing this is to avoid read inconsistencies when performing these operations, eg: when delete query is running first i dont want someone else to read the data and then insert query runs.

Comment: It might make more sense to use a MERGE with an UPDATE statement, but do so with a stored procedure that dynamically generates the column list for you based on the source and target table definitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake does not implement the full SQL MERGE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489537/snowflake-does-not-implement-the-full-sql-merge-statement)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query, you can run:

```
select id, description, test
from temp
union all
select id, description, test
from source
where not exists (select 1 from temp t where source.id = temp.id);
```

If you want to modify the data:

```
merge into source_table
    using temp_table 
    on source_table.id = temp_table.id
when matched then 
    update set source_table.test = temp_table.test
when not matched then
    insert into source_table (id, description, test)
        values (temp_table.id, temp_table.description, temp_table.test);
```

Your naming convention is a little confusing relative to the normal documentation for `merge`.  Typical naming would call "target" what you are calling "source", and then "source" is the new data in `temp_table`.

Comment: in case of merge as i mentioned i would want to avoid using update because when generalizing i would want to run the same query for many tables and i will not have the individual column names to update.

Comment: Yes i want to modify source_table.

Comment: Actual problem i am trying to solve is: 
`"delete from $tableName where $dpPrimaryKey in " (select $PrimaryKey from $tempTableName);`   
`insert into $tableName (select * from $tempTableName);"`
I have these 2 individual statements i want to get the desired result in 1 query. 

@Gordon any suggestions when it comes to generalizing this..?

Comment: @tech_geek . . . I thought the reference was to an `update` command, so this is accomplished in one statement.  If you don't want to use `update`, then your question doesn't make sense.  This does what your question is asking for.